# Create SDK in Intellij on Mac: how to type in / paste in path to JDK?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I am trying to add the java6 JDK that is located here:

/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk

When I go to File  | Project Structure | SDK's and click on "add" , it asks me to navigate. Is there any way to paste in the path - instead of doing the tedious point and click starting at the root directory / and steadily building the path manually??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a general issue with MAc File Open dialogs.  You need to type Command Shift G to open the "goto" dialog .

However pasting the path via Command-V still does not work - at least not on my OS X Lion machine. I have to type the whole path manually.

Credit for the answer - and more info - can be found at the following.

[http://www.macworld.com/article/1161022/copy_paste_file_paths.html][1]

Comment: Worth noting that tab completion works in the goto dialog